# Erro no ajax .JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Olá,O código a seguir irá apresentar uma tabela com valores.Estou recuperando o valor da célula da tabela que o usuário clica através desta função `$(this).text()` no javaScript. Tenho de enviar essa informação adquira por está função,por um um ajax,para uma pagina que se chama (`Tela_Escolha_Perguntas_correcao.php`) que está  presente na mesma pasta do código abaixo. Nesta (`Tela_Escolha_Perguntas_correcao.php`) tela quero que apareça o valor enviado para ela.Observe que na construção da  tabela estou criando um link para (`Tela_Escolha_Perguntas_correcao.php`) para quando o usuário clicar em cima ser direcionado para ela.

Tentei usar o `$_GET['nomeGrupo']` e não obtive exito.

```
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         var valor;

         var nomeGrupo;

     $('.classGrupo').click(

     function () {

      nomeGrupo=$(this).text();


      valor ={'nomeGrupo':nomeGrupo};

     $.ajax(
         {
             type: 'GET',
             url:'Tela_Escolha_Perguntas_correcao.php',
             data: valor,
             async: false         
         }
     ).done(function (retorno) {
         alert(retorno);
     });

     }
     );
     });

  </script>
 </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <figure>
        <img  <img src="../imagens/logotipo.png">
     </figure>
     </div>
     <div id="divBusca">
        <input type="text" id="txtBusca" placeholder="Buscar..."/>
          <button id="btnBusca">Buscar</button>
     </div>
     <div id="IDsair">
        <a href="Sair_Sessao.php">SAIR</a>
     </div>
  </header>
   <div id="id_tabela">
      <table >
         <tr>
            <th>Grupos</th>
         </tr>
         <?php
            for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){

               echo " <tr>
              <td class='classGrupo'><a href='Tela_Escolha_Perguntas_correcao.php'>valor,$i</a></td>         
           </tr>";
           }
           ?>
     </table>
  </div>
```

Segunda Tela (`Tela_Escolha_Perguntas_correcao.php`) O primeiro código envia o texto da célula da tabela pra essa segunda tela, e o usuário tmb é direcionado pra esta tela podendo ver o conteúdo enviado.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <body>
  <div class="principal">

    <header>

    <figure id="logo">
        <img src="../imagens/logotipo.png">
    </figure>

    <span><h1><?php echo'',$_GET['nomeGrupo']; ?></h1></span>

    <div id="logoUserADM">

    <figure id="logoADM">
       <img src="../imagens/administrador.png">
    </figure>

    <figure id="logoUser">
        <img src="../imagens/imagemPerfilA.png">
    </figure>

    </div>
</header>

<section>
    <label>Criar Perguntas</label>
    <label>Corrigir Perguntas</label>

    <div id="imagensBotoes">

    <a href="jk"><img src="../imagens/CostrucaoAtividade.jpg"> </a>

    <a href="jk"><img src="../imagens/Correcao.png"> </a>
  <div>
</section>
 </header>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **De acordo com o que você pretende** "Segunda Tela (Tela_Escolha_Perguntas_correcao.php) O primeiro código envia o texto da célula da tabela pra essa segunda tela, **e o usuário tmb é direcionado** pra esta tela podendo ver o conteúdo enviado.", **não precisa usar ajax nem bibliotecas**, basta passar via GET os parâmetros diretamente no link a ser clicado:

```
<?php
     for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
        echo " <tr>
        <td class='classGrupo'><a href='Tela_Escolha_Perguntas_correcao.php?nomeGrupo=valor,".$i."'>valor,$i</a></td>        
       </tr>";
     }
?>
```

> Se tiver que passar um vetor, transforme o conteúdo deste vetor em uma string, separando os elementos por algum caractere que nunca vá ser usado no conteúdo dos ítens. Geralmente os desenvolvedores usam vírgula com o fim de separar os elementos. Eu prefiro o caractere pipe “|”, devido ao fato que este não consta nas regras da língua portuguesa para qualquer função.

```
//array com a lista de produtos
$produtos = array(0 =>"relogio digital",
1 =>"mouse",
2 =>"arame para cerca",
3 =>"bateria de celular",
4 =>"doce de abobora",
5 =>"tv de plasma",
6 =>"prato de porcelana");
```

criando a string com a função php implode

```
  $string_array = implode("|", $produtos);

  echo "<tr>
        <td class='classGrupo'><a href='Tela_Escolha_Perguntas_correcao.php?nomeGrupo=".$string_array."'>enviar</a></td>        
  </tr>";
```

> **Um bom exemplo do uso do AJAX são as aplicações sem carregamento de uma nova página.**

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('td').click(function(){

       var nomeGrupo=$(this).text();
       var dataString = {"nomeGrupo":nomeGrupo};

              $.ajax({
                url: 'Tela_Escolha_Perguntas_correcao.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataString,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $("#resultados").html("Carregando...");
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $("#resultados").html(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#resultados").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
                }
             });//ajax 

    });

}); 

</script>

</head>
<body>
   <header>
      <div>
         <figure>
           <img  <img src="../imagens/logotipo.png">
         </figure>
     </div>
     <div id="divBusca">
        <input type="text" id="txtBusca" placeholder="Buscar..."/>
          <button id="btnBusca">Buscar</button>
     </div>
     <div id="IDsair">
        <a href="Sair_Sessao.php">SAIR</a>
     </div>
  </header>
   <div id="id_tabela">
      <table >
         <tr>
            <th>Grupos</th>
         </tr>
         <?php
            for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
               echo " <tr>
              <td class='classGrupo'>valor,$i</td>         
           </tr>";
           }
           ?>
     </table>
  </div>

  <div id="resultados"></div>

</body>
```